# Java convert Map<String, Object> to Map<String, ?>

Tags: java, java-7

I am using JDK 7, 
How do I efficiently convert `List<Map<String,Object>> to List<Map<String,?>>`

The code snippet is as follows

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = fetchData(qry, providedFiltersAndParams);

List<Map<String, ?>> convertedData = new ArrayList<>();
for ( Map<String, Object> eachRow : data ) {
    convertedData.add(eachRow);
}
filler.fillData(convertedData);
```

fecthData returns `List<Map<String, Object>>` . However The filler.fillData expects argument as `List<Map<String, ?>>`

I would like to avoid the creation of a new list and for loop.

Comment: You could just cast to `(List)` to bypass the generic type information.

Comment: Ah, this seems to be simplest and efficient. We dont need to create a new list and copy objs. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
filler.fillData(new ArrayList<>(data));
```

`new ArrayList<>(data)` copies the objecs into a new ArrayList which adapts directly the signature of `List<Map<String, ?>>`.

Comment: My compiler reports as incompatibe type. khelwood's comment worked for me